# How to Simulate an HTTP GET Request on 1000 Fake Servers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, server, get

I'm a newbie and a little confused by a task.

I have a list of 1000 or so fake servers. I have to do a GET request on each of the servers and endpoints that'll generate json like this:

```
[{"Application":"Cache2","Version":"1.0.1","Uptime":4637719417,"Request_Count":5194800029,"Error_Count":1042813251,"Success_Count":4151986778},
{"Application":"Webapp1","Version":"1.2.2","Uptime":1572762564,"Request_Count":2171887540,"Error_Count":1066265249,"Success_Count":1105622291},
{"Application":"Database2","Version":"1.1.2","Uptime":5292759176,"Request_Count":4130319104,"Error_Count":839310048,"Success_Count":3291009056}]
```

My confusion is not about how to write the code but more about how to do a GET request on fake servers, when there's no data?

Is this where I would using mocking? Or some other way to simulate the data?

Also, my code has to work against any server file that is passed in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/httmock/